# Pattern matching a drawing with basic shapes

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, machine-learning, pattern-matching

I have a python list of coordinates saved like this : `[(34,55),(44,66)....]`.
This list indicates a hand drawn line on the screen. Now I need to check if this line/shape matches with some pre saved similar lists of basic shapes like square, circle, triangle, etc. (Basically I need to recognise user gestures.) Please suggest some machine learning technique to achieve it. Suggest the link if this is a duplicate. (I prefer a python solution for this.)

P.S : The shape that user is inputting comes from a camera/video. It is the path traversed by an object I am tracking with opencv. Now I need to figure what shapes the user is drawing by waving the object in front of the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds pretty similar to what I did in my Bachelors thesis about "[On-line Recognition of Handwritten Mathematical Symbols](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.09030)".

You can recognize those patterns with a [neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). Interpolate the lines, normalize the points on a line to a fixed number, take the (x,y) coordinates as input features and the types of shape as output nodes (one node for circle, one node for triangle, ...).

You can create such a network with TensorFlow. Here are [my two cents about TensorFlow](http://martin-thoma.com/tensor-flow-quick/).

### Dynamic Time Warping

This is a pattern matching approach. See my bachelors thesis or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).

### Alternatives to Machine Learning

If you want something simpler and if you only have a tiny amount of classes (e.g. < 30), then you could probably also hand-engineer an algorithm. I recommend to have a look at the [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to find the most important points. I've described it in my bachelor's thesis. When you go to [this interactive preprocessing page](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/render/?raw_data_id=331161&show_points=on&dot_reduction_threshold=0.2&dehooking_threshold=20&minimum_time_delay_filter_constant=10&smoothing_applications=1&smooth1=0&smooth2=1&smooth3=0&douglas_peucker=on&epsilon=10&cubic_spline_points=20) you can get a feeling for this algorithm (you can draw something on write-math.com, click on "Drawing" below the canvas, click on "Preprocessing" and apply it by checking the checkbox)

### See also

- [On-line Graphics Recognition](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~xj3a/research/publications/PG02.pdf)
- [Online Sketch Recognition: Geometric Shapes](http://lib.tkk.fi/Dipl/2011/urn100500.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. But is there a simpler way for this? Artificial neural network sounds like an overkill for such a simple task. I was hoping I could use numpy or some matpolib to get this done.

Comment: ANNs are actually quite simple to use and they perform best when you have enough training data (at least 50 examples per class, better would be something like 150 examples per class).

Comment: @bhargav I've just expanded my answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The papers about Online Graphics recognition are about exactly what I  asked. Thank you for the links.